firebase redirect in chrome extension
I have developed an extension where I want when user signs up, an email is sent to him. And once verified they're then redirected to the home page.
I'm using onAuthStateChanged to handle it, but it's not working as i m expecting it . I have implemented interval system,
its not an Regular web app its an extension hence thru the firebase console where we change the url isnt possible
attaching the current code snippet of the verify email page and the config/auth of the firebase
Issue being face The flow is not working as I expected. When the user signs up, they are taken to the Verify Email page, which listens to the user auth status (true or false). Once the user verifies their email, the status should change to true, and they should be redirected to the home page. However, the redirection doesn't happen. There are no errors in the console, and when I close the extension and reopen it, I am already on the home page, indicating that the email has been verified successfully. what i want is that when the user verifies the email and the extension side panel is open at the same time its redirect to the home page not making it to close extension and re open it
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { auth } from './config/firebase-config'; // Adjust the path accordingly
import { sendEmailVerification, onAuthStateChanged } from 'firebase/auth';
import { useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';

const VerifyEmail = () => {
  const [error, setError] = useState('');
  const [message, setMessage] = useState('');
  const navigate = useNavigate();

  useEffect(() => {
    const unsubscribe = onAuthStateChanged(auth, (user) => {
      if (!user) {
        console.log('No user found, redirecting to login...');
        navigate('/login', { replace: true });
        return;
      }

      const checkEmailVerification = async () => {
        await user.reload(); // Reload the user to get the updated verification status
        const freshUser = auth.currentUser;

        if (freshUser?.emailVerified) {
          console.log('Email verified, redirecting to home...');
          navigate('/home', { replace: true });
        }
      };

      // Check verification every 3 seconds, but limit to once after verification
      const intervalId = setInterval(() => {
        checkEmailVerification();
      }, 3000);

      // Cleanup function to avoid memory leaks
      return () => {
        clearInterval(intervalId);
      };
    });

    return () => {
      unsubscribe();
    };
  }, [navigate]);

  const resendVerificationEmail = async () => {
    const user = auth.currentUser;
    if (!user) {
      setError('No user found. Please try logging in again.');
      return;
    }

    try {
      await sendEmailVerification(user);
      setMessage('Verification email sent! Please check your inbox and spam folder.');
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Error sending verification email:', error);
      setError('Could not send verification email. Please try again later.');
    }
  };

  return (
    <div className="max-w-md mx-auto mt-8 p-6 bg-white rounded-lg shadow-md">
      <h2 className="text-2xl font-bold mb-6 text-center">Verify Your Email</h2>
      <div className="space-y-4">
        <div className="bg-blue-50 p-4 rounded">
          <p className="text-sm text-blue-800">
            A verification email has been sent to your email address.
            Please check your inbox and click the verification link.
          </p>
        </div>

        <button
          onClick={resendVerificationEmail}
          className="w-full bg-blue-500 text-white py-2 px-4 rounded hover:bg-blue-600 transition-colors"
        >
          Resend Verification Email
        </button>

        {error && (
          <div className="bg-red-50 p-3 rounded">
            <p className="text-sm text-red-800">{error}</p>
          </div>
        )}
        
        {message && (
          <div className="bg-green-50 p-3 rounded">
            <p className="text-sm text-green-800">{message}</p>
          </div>
        )}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default VerifyEmail;
//auth js code for handling it is 
export const signup = async (email, password) => {
    try {
        const userCredential = await createUserWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password);
        const user = userCredential.user;
        await sendEmailVerification(user);
        await saveUserData(user);
        return user;
    } catch (error) {
        
        throw error;
    }
};

export const checkEmailVerification = (user) => {
    return user && user.emailVerified;
};

Issue being face The flow is not working as I expected. When the user signs up, they are taken to the Verify Email page, which listens to the user auth status (true or false). Once the user verifies their email, the status should change to true, and they should be redirected to the home page. However, the redirection doesn't happen. There are no errors in the console, and when I close the extension and reopen it, I am already on the home page, indicating that the email has been verified successfully. what i want is that when the user verifies the email and the extension side panel is open at the same time its redirect to the home page not making it to close extension and re open it
